# Assign a custom attribute to a strongly defined MVC class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In MVC3 how would I create a custom attribute to a strongly defined class (apologies about terminology, I'm learning as I go here)  so that I can use it like:

`[CustomValue(AttributeMappingName =  "first.name")`]

I would like to be able to display 'first-name' within my view, I realise this is static for every Patient_FirstName but I wish to access a custom mappingname client side.

Context:

```
public class FormStandard_Model
    {
        [Required()]
        [Key]
        public string My_ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(32, MinimumLength = 2)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [CustomValue(AttributeMappingName =  "first.name")]
        public string Patient_FirstName { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to create a custom `ModelMetadataProvider` so that the data in your custom attribute will be available in your view. See this answer:
[Custom Data Annotations ASP.NET MVC C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548156/custom-data-annotations-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp)

Comment: Just to add I continued on using the following information to display this value: http://www.kristofclaes.be/blog/2011/08/26/an-htmlhelper-to-display-if-a-field-is-required-or-not-in-aspnet-mvc-3/