# How to change models editable atttribute based on a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Based on user credentials, I will allow users to edit a field or not on a Razor View.

So I currently have one model which I can do this for the properties I forbid:

```
[Editable(allowEdit=false)]
public string FirstName {get;set;}
```

but when I add the attribute whether or not a user has permission to edit it, they won't be able to. I cannot change the fields in Razor View either as we use a very different way of rendering model properties.

Any idea how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Not the same question, but the answer could be usefull. [Custom Data Annotations ASP.NET MVC C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548156/custom-data-annotations-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp) Edit: I got to this answer because `Editable` does not seem to do anything as `Readonly` with `Html.TextBoxFor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to create custom validation attribute and use that, in it you can inject your boolean and check and make it conditional (in C#).

The better option is to use Fluent Validation - its much easier to work with in these cases, when you need conditional validation. Also it will keep your models cleaner.

So if you can - use [Fluent validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/), if not, just define your own property and control it in your code including all conditions. Examples and links to libraries are [here](http://andrewtwest.com/2011/01/10/conditional-validation-with-data-annotations-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Here is another option for you - complete library built with aim to easy the work you trying to achieve : http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

Hope this helps